# How to write types for a nested function in a destructured object?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to write types for `body`, `header` and `footer` but cannot find a way to access it. Usually I've got these kind of problems when the object is destructured.

From `body`, `header` and `footer` I get the error: 
"const body: any. 
Property 'body' does not exist on type '{}'."

```js
interface ModalProps {
  onClick: () => void;
 
}

const Modal: React.FunctionComponent<ModalProps> = props => {
  useContext(ModalContext);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [content = {}, setContent] = useState({});
  const show = (content = {}) => {
    const { body, header, footer } = content;
    if (!body && !header && !footer) {
      setContent({ content });
    } else {
      setContent({ body, header, footer });
    }
    setIsOpen(true);
  };
```

I've tried to insert it in the interface but with no success:

```js
interface ModalProps {
  onClick: () => void;
     content: {
     body: any
     }
 
}
```

Also tried:

```js
const { body, header, footer }: {body: any, header: any, footer: any} = content;
```

but get the error message: "Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type '{ body: any; header: any; footer: any; }': body, header, footer"

Any hints would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, `content` in your `show` function is type `{}` because you haven't told TypeScript anything different, and that's all it can infer from the parameter default (`{}`). The type `{}` doesn't have `body`, etc.

You need to tell TypeScript what `content` is. I'm guessing a bit at what you want `content` to be, but you probably what something along these lines:

```
interface Content {
  body?: string;
  header?: string;
  footer?: string;
  content?: Content;
}
```

Then `setContent` would be:

```
function setContent(content: Content) {
  // ...
}
```

and `show` would be:

```
const show = (content: Content = {}) => {
  const { body, header, footer } = content;
  if (!body && !header && !footer) {
    setContent({ content });
  } else {
    setContent({ body, header, footer });
  }
};
```

However, it seems a bit odd to make `setContent` have to deal with the same thing that `show` has to deal with (checking to see if there are `body`, `header`, and `footer` values or just a single `content` value). You might be better off overloading `setContent`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is your default `content` on the show function: `const show = (content = {}) => {`.

This creates the possibility of content being an empty object. That is why you receive "Property 'body' does not exist on type '{}'.". Typescript infers that is possible for `body` not to exist in your object `content`.

If you are not going to call show without arguments, you can simply remove your default. On the other hand, if you want to type your show function, you could make this interface:

```js
type RawContent = String;
interface ContentWithHeaderAndFooter {
 header: any;
 body: any;
 footer: any;
}
type Content = RawContent | ContentWithHeaderAndFooter;
const show = (content: Content) => {...}
```

I believe this would cover all you uses cases, but for me, it is a bit overkill, I would simply remove the default of the `show` function.